# CORS issue - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error Upon POST (Jquery Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, amazon-s3, cors

I am making a POST request to AWS s3 API gateway using JQUERY & AJAX. Upon submit, the shadow is updated. However I get an error in the console. Here is the ajax part of the code,

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "<aws-url>" ,
   data: myJSON,
   crossDomain : true,
   //dataType: 'jsonp',
   headers :{
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
   success: function(result) {
        console.log("done");
   }
});
```

The POST works and the shadow is updated, but I still get this error at the console. Also I am aware that postman can't be used with POST method.
Here is the error:
Failed to load :No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't understand whats going on. Please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: Actually I have already seen that Post and that did not help. So I asked this question myself. Actually I am posting to an API gateway in S3. Jsonp didnt work as i am making a POST request. Also, as I said, the POST works but I get the error in my console which reveals the url. Thus, I want to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable CORS in you API gateway like below.

If you don't have OPTIONS added, please follow below steps (If OPTIONS already there just add CORS),

- Create a new OPTIONS method under the /services resource
- Create and populate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin/Method/Headers in the OPTIONS method.

Enable CORS like below after creating OPTIONS

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already enabled CORS. I have set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*' and Access-Control-Allow-Headers to the default values provided to me that are Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorizaiton, X-API-key and X-Amz-Security-Token. Also I set the Access-Control-Allow-Method to POST, GET and OPTIONS. Still doesn't work. The methods are lambda functions and do not require authorization. However I have not checked on any of the Gateway Responses. Please help.

Comment: I am sure you might have deployed API after the changes but just want to see confirm it

Comment: Yes. I deployed the API and then made a POST request which updated the shadow. However I think i don't get the access-control-allow-origin in the response header. The response itself is null which means the POST was sucessful. Still the error in the console has not been solved.

Comment: Can you please share your handler code if API gateway is triggering Lambda?

Comment: Can you please share the handler as well if it is connected to Lambda?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!!!!!!! I went to OPTIONS method. There I went to Method Response and inside Http status I added Access-Control-Allow-Header, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods. I figured as the prefilght request was OPTIONS method, so I should change the settings in the options method and it worked. Thanks so much for the reply though :)